# How to disable Insecure HTTP methods in application in java

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, servlets, security-constraint

I have a web application developed in Restful webservice and java. Iam using Jersey library. My team ran Appscan tool on the application.That tool says
Insecure HTTP Methods Enabled   on https:///AppName/.

EDIT:

1. I would like to know how to disable DELETE methods here.
2. When I make a option request to Server it should not list delete method in allowed method in header.
   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Define in `web.xml` a security constraint with an empty auth constraint on the desired URL pattern and the given HTTP methods.

The below example restricts ALL `DELETE` and `TRACE` requests, regardless of URL and user.

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Restricted HTTP methods.</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <!-- You can specify multiple HTTP methods here. -->
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

The effect is a [HTTP 403 Forbidden](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4) response.

Comment: Hi @BalusC , Thanks for you prompt reply. the fix you suggestes is already there and its already throwing 403.... What I want is to  remove delete from the Allowed method header

Comment: Why didn't you state that as such in your question?

Comment: I don't have Jersey at hands right now, but RESTEasy already doesn't do that when there's no `@DELETE` method anywhere in the API. Are you sure the `Allow` header is coming from Jersey and not from container or perhaps a proxy (e.g. Apache HTTPD)? Namely, this would indicate a bug in Jersey.